# Send SMS text from HTML page on Android phone without displaying the SMS window

Tags: javascript, android, html, sms

I'd like to know if it was possible, using only a HTML page (Javascript allowed), to send a SMS to a number. I know it's possible to get the GPS position after having asked the user if he allowed the page to access this data, I imagine there is a "Do you allow this page to send SMS?" message I could display.
Of course, I don't want the SMS window to display or to use a third party API, I'd like my app to work without internet.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, at least in Google Chrome.  You can verify this by looking in your device settings and confirming that Google Chrome does not request SMS permissions - thus, there is no way that it could send an SMS message without opening the SMS app for the user to send it themself.

Comment: I use Firefox, but you're right, when I check the authorizations of all the browsers, none of them allow to send SMS. That's a shame, but I can easily understand why.
Thank you.